# Passport js while deserializing users returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, serialization, passport.js

So I used passportjs for authentication and it worked fine for a while but now all of a sudden it is giving null while deserializing users even though the user with provided id is present in the session.

**CODE**

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import passport from 'passport';
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';
import { PoliceStation } from '../Models/policestation.model.js';

class PoliceController {
  constructor() {
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.initializePassport();
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }

  initializePassport() {
    console.log('Initializing passport 1')
    passport.use('policestation-local',
    new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
      try {
        console.log('Incoming name:', username);
        console.log('Incoming password:', password);
  
        const user = await PoliceStation.findOne({ name: username, password: password });
  
        if (!user) {
          console.log('User not found');
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password' });
        }
  
        console.log('User found:', user);
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in LocalStrategy:', error.message);
        return done(error);
      }
    })
  );  
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
      console.log('Serialize User:', user.id);
      done(null, user.id);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
      console.log('Deserialize User ID:', id);
      try {
        const user = await PoliceStation.findById(id);
        console.log('Deserialized User:', user);
        done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Deserialize User Error:', error);
        done(error);
      }
    });
    

    

  }  


initializeRoutes() {
  this.router.use(
    session({
      secret: '12345',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false, 
        maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
      },
    })
  );

  this.router.use(passport.initialize());
  this.router.use(passport.session());


  const requireLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Authentication Status:', req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log('User Object:', req.user);

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    }
  };

this.router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('policestation-local'), (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

    const user = req.user;
    console.log('Authenticated User:', user);

   
    console.log('Session Data:', req.session);

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', user });
  } else {
 
    console.log('Authentication failed');
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Login failed' });
  }
});
this.router.get('/checklogin', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log('User is authenticated:', req.user);
    res.json({ loggedIn: true, user: req.user });
  } else {
    console.log('User is not authenticated');
    res.json({ loggedIn: false });
  }
});
    this.router.get('/', this.hello.bind(this));
    this.router.post('/logout', this.logout.bind(this));
    this.router.get('/map/:_id', requireLogin, this.getMap.bind(this));
    this.router.get('/officer/:_id', requireLogin, this.getPoliceOfficers.bind(this));
  }

  async hello(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }

  logout(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Session destroy error:', err);
        return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }

      res.send('Logged out successfully');
    });
  }

  async getMap(req, res) {
    try {
      const userId = req.params._id;
      const userInfo = await PoliceStation.findById(userId);

      if (!userInfo) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
      }

      const userLocation = userInfo.location;
      res.json({ location: userLocation });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Map Error:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  }

  async getPoliceOfficers(req, res) {
    try {
      const userId = req.params._id;
      const userInfo = await PoliceStation.findById(userId).populate('policeOfficers').exec();

      if (!userInfo) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
      }

      const policeOfficers = userInfo.policeOfficers || [];
      res.json({ policeOfficers });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Get Police Officers Error:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
  }
}

export default PoliceController;
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
Incoming name: Bani Gala
Incoming password: 12345678
User found: {
  location: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [ 73.14266502857208, 33.67536763416153 ]
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9"),
  name: 'Bani Gala',
  address: 'Bani Gala, Islamabad',
  phone: 519255339,
  password: '12345678',
  rating: 5,
  __v: 9,
  policeOfficers: [
    new ObjectId("646e3bf76c974f42bcbb055d"),
    new ObjectId("646f67acdff8e98bf7fcf530"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7aa88960bcfdc00352a"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7b788960bcfdc003532"),
    new ObjectId("6473905b525377ad83c76d27"),
    new ObjectId("652ba58332ff7f5df0014395"),
    new ObjectId("652d46a4c1f1ea9992302b77"),
    new ObjectId("652d6f88c34a3964bc9ebae4"),
    new ObjectId("652d7099c34a3964bc9ebb04")
  ]
}
Serialize User: 646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9
Authenticated User: {
  location: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [ 73.14266502857208, 33.67536763416153 ]
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9"),
  name: 'Bani Gala',
  address: 'Bani Gala, Islamabad',
  phone: 519255339,
  password: '12345678',
  rating: 5,
  __v: 9,
  policeOfficers: [
    new ObjectId("646e3bf76c974f42bcbb055d"),
    new ObjectId("646f67acdff8e98bf7fcf530"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7aa88960bcfdc00352a"),
    new ObjectId("646fc7b788960bcfdc003532"),
    new ObjectId("6473905b525377ad83c76d27"),
    new ObjectId("652ba58332ff7f5df0014395"),
    new ObjectId("652d46a4c1f1ea9992302b77"),
    new ObjectId("652d6f88c34a3964bc9ebae4"),
    new ObjectId("652d7099c34a3964bc9ebb04")
  ]
}
Session Data: Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-12-03T14:25:04.606Z,
    originalMaxAge: 604800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  passport: { user: '646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9' }
}
Deserialize User ID: 646e2f653433e58b4b36bbc9
Deserialized User: null
User is not authenticated
```

**Another controller**

I created another controller and used passport authentication in that. It is working absolutely fine. Funny thing is I basically copy pasted the whole auth from this controller and just changed the model name according to that controller. That one is working fine and the one which was originally supposed to work fine is causing problems

Comment: dose the user data actually exist in the db? because mongodb returns `null` in case there is no document is stored.

Comment: Yes, the data exists in the db

Comment: I am not sure if mongodb accepts mongo id as "string". You might try to pass it as an object. For instance `{ "_id": ObjectId("123") }`. Not sure if you actually need to parse the string to ObjectId but worth the try.